# Linking classes in Geany

Tags: c++, class, linker

I am writing a CLI application for Linux in Geany (a C++ IDE). I want to link a simple config file reader class so it can be used in my program. Just including it doesn't work, I get undefined reference errors. I know how to do this in Dev-C++ on Windows, but not Geany. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You are not linking in appropriate libraries. There must be something called Linker Options. Check the documentation out.

Comment: The only way to do it is to change the linker and compiler command line options. What options do you use?

Comment: I don't use that IDE -- sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the path as you would do it on command line. Configuration menu can be found at Build->Set build commands.

For bigger prjects it's recommenden to use e.g. Makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

For Geanie you have to #include both the header and the .cpp otherwise it will keep giving you the undefined reference error. It worked for me; hopefully it will work for you.